# Excel remains in the background

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

using access VBA I open an excel file, I perform a series of operations (as per the following code) I close everything but excel remains running.
In fact, if I go and repeat the same procedure I get an error: the file is read only. I have to open "Process Explorer" and manually kill the process.
Where am I wrong?
Thank you

```
`Public Function agg_file_codifiche(Cognome, Nome, CF, password As String) As Long
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oExcelWrkBk As Excel.Workbook
Dim oExcelWrSht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlsfile, xlssheet As String
Dim ur, code As Long

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    xlsfile = "C:\Users\*****\Documenti\_LAVORO_\CODIFICHE_UNIPAM\Codifiche unipam.xlsx"
    xlssheet = "Codifiche"
        
    Set oExcelWrkBk = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(xlsfile, , False)
    Set oExcelWrSht = oExcelWrkBk.Sheets(xlssheet)
    oExcel.Visible = False

    With oExcelWrSht
        ur = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    
        badge_code = .Cells(ur + 1, 1).Value
        code = .Cells(ur + 1, 2).Value
    
        .Cells(ur + 1, 3).Value = Cognome & " " & Nome
        .Cells(ur + 1, 4).Value = password
        .Cells(ur + 1, 5).Value = CF
        .Cells(ur + 1, 8).Value = Format(Date, "Short Date")
    End With
    
    oExcelWrkBk.Save
    oExcelWrkBk.Close
    oExcel.Quit

Exit_Point:
    Set oExcelWrSht = Nothing
    Set oExcelWrkBk = Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    agg_file_codifiche = code
    Exit Function
    
Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err & " - " & Err.Description
    GoTo Exit_Point
End Function`
```

Comment: Not tested but you do `Dim oExcel As Excel.Application` and then `Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` so it looks like you are creating 2 instances of Excel?

Comment: Nope. `Dim oExcel As Excel.Application` just declared a variable. Like `Dim ws As Worksheet` would declare a Worksheet variable (but doesn't create a Worksheet). It would be different if you would use `Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application`

Comment: You already have got the answer... If you would have a proper error handler, you would have discovered the error on your own :) Also You had to manually kill the process because of the line  `oExcel.Visible = False` My recommendation is: Till the time you are not 100% sure that your code is completely error free, do not hide your objects. Once everything is ok, then you may hide it. In your case, if you wouldn't have set the visible property to `False` you would have visually seen the Excel application remained open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed an object reference. It should read:

```
ur = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

and not:

```
ur = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: with this modification it worked immediately

Comment: Rory, while it is a good habit to add the object reference, but this would not cause the application to remain open. Since user is using Early binding, he would get the correct value for Rows.Count. I tested OPs code without adding the object reference, and the excel applicaiton closed properly...

Comment: I suspect, OP has not posted the complete code. An error is happening somewhere else because of which the code is exiting without closing the applicaiton. And since OP has `oExcel.Visible = False`, he doesn't realize the workbook is still open. OP mentioned **In fact, if I go and repeat the same procedure I get an error: the file is read only.**

Comment: @SiddharthRout actually no. The unqualified reference to Rows will create an implicit (application) variable that will only be cleared when the calling application is closed. That’s why adding the dot cures the problem.

Comment: Rory, It is not the application which is remaing hanging but the workbook is also open as well and hence user gets the Read-Only alert. I am aware of the implicit variable issue. It usually happens with Interop and hence GC collect. In VBA, I have never seen this happen. Also like i said, I tested it and there was no instance left open :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout it’s a pretty common question in vba and the answer is almost always this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems with your code:

**(a)** You have an error handler (Label `Error_Handler`) but you are not using it (you don't have a statement `On Error Goto Error_Handler` in your code). If you now hit an error and your calling code uses an own error handler, the workbook is not closed and Excel is not stopped.

**(b)** If your error handler would be used and an error occurred, the code would also skip the statements that closes workbook and Excel.

Code could look like:

```
Public Function agg_file_codifiche(Cognome, Nome, CF, password As String) As Long
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oExcelWrkBk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oExcelWrSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlsfile, xlssheet As String
    Dim ur, code As Long

    On Error Goto Error_Handler
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    (...)      

    oExcelWrkBk.Save

Exit_Point:  
    If Not oExcelWrkBk is Nothing Then 
        oExcelWrkBk.Close
        Set oExcelWrkBk = Nothing
    End If
   
    If Not oExcel Is Nothing Then 
        oExcel.Quit
        Set oExcel = Nothing
    End If

    agg_file_codifiche = code
    Exit Function
    
Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err & " - " & Err.Description
    GoTo Exit_Point
End Function
```

Btw: Is there a reason you use Late Binding instead of Early Binding?

**Update**: As the code already uses Early Binding to declare the variables, I updated the statement that opens the Excel Application.

Comment: OP is not using late binding. The variables are declared as specific object types, not `Object`.

Comment: You are right. Actually my code included error handling but I forgot about it in my changes... sorry!
`    On Error Resume Next
    Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Else
        On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    End If`

Comment: @Rory: You're right - and not right. The variables are declared using early binding (I admit I didn't notice that), but the code used `CreateObject` to create an Excel App.

Comment: The method used to instantiate an object does not determine its binding context in any way. The OP's code is early bound. :)

Comment: OK, true. But the compiler wouldn't throw an error when the statement would be `CreateObject("Word.Application")`.

Comment: Nor would it with `New` so I don't really get your point?

Comment: Yes it would. `Set oExcel = New Word.Application` would throw a compiler error (type mismatch), not only a runtime error.

Comment: Not here. The only error is at runtime and that is handled by the error handler.

Comment: I was 100% sure that this gets a compile error - but you're right...

Answer (score 0):

As well as setting the Excel objects to nothing, you also need to close/quit them:

```
Exit_Point:
    Set oExcelWrSht = Nothing
    oExcelWrkBk.Close
    Set oExcelWrkBk = Nothing
    oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    agg_file_codifiche = code
Exit Function
```